# How to validate composed strings with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate/write a regex of this form: `uuid` OR `uuid-cust-uuid`

It should `ONLY` return `true` when I test with a valid `uuid` OR a composed uuid like `uuid-cust-uuid`

Here is the regex I have written thus far:

```
  const uuid =
  /[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\-cust\-[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})?/;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `test` method and it will do the job.

```js
const regexUUID = /[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\-cust\-[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})?/;

const uuid = 'ec3bf3c6-85be-4169-971c-0c49be945b51';

console.log(regexUUID.test(uuid));
```

Edited:
As for your requirement, you can try something like this:

```js
// Wrtie base uuid regex
const baseUUIDRegex = '[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}';

// Then use it inside another regex like this
const customRegex = `^${baseUUIDRegex}-cust-${baseUUIDRegex}$`;
console.log('ec3bf3c6-85be-4169-971c-0c49be945b51-cust-ec3bf3c6-85be-4169-971c-0c49be945b51'.match(customRegex));
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I'm aware of the `test()` method for regex. My issue is writing a valid regex to suit those conditions originally raised @Ubaid Ullah

Comment: Please see the edited version of the answer. You can write your regex like I demonstrated in the answer.
const baseUUIDRegex = '[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}';
const UUIDRegex = `^${baseUUIDRegex}-cust-${baseUUIDRegex}$`;